# Using Buildfire Navgation's navigateTo to plugins that require user purchase

Tags: buildfire

I have been using Buildfire's internal navigation.navigateTo method and recently noticed it's not working for plugins that require a customer to have purchased the feature.

It opens the plugin but the query string is not getting processed. Console logging the window.location.search value from the plugin that is navigated TO shows that the query string passed in the navigateTo method is not carrying over to the opened plugin, resulting in the plugin simply opening to its main page, whereas the purpose of what I'm attempting to do is to drill down to a specific item within the plugin and display that.

When navigating to a plugin that does not require purchase, the function works as desired, and the window.location.search value does include the query string I passed from the previous plugin. For context, this is how the method is formatted. I've verified that the variables are all correct by logging them from the function that fires this navigation method.

```
buildfire.navigation.navigateTo({
     pluginId: pluginId,
     instanceId: recipe.instanceId,
     queryString: `recipeId=${recipe.recipeId}`,
});
```

This was working previously within my plugin, and I have not changed anything related to its navigation.

Is there something I'm missing in regards to paid plugins that might interfere with the location.search parameter?

Comment: I believe this was a bug that was logged and fixed. Can you please confirm?

Comment: @Daniel_Madain Yes it is working now. Is there a better way to log such issues in the future? Thank you

Comment: Its great to hear its working for you now. If you have an Account Manager, speak to them explaining that you think this is a potential bug. They will open an internal ticket for you. If they think it's just a question, they will suggest posting here for the larger community to benefit.